# Setting viewport width is ignored on cordova 7

Tags: android, html, cordova, meta-tags, phonegap

A couple of years ago I developed a cordova/phonegap application. I needed to fix screen width to 1200 (some devices had a width of 962px) so I added a meta tag to set viewport content width like

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200, user-scalable-no">
```

Recently I've had to add some new features and upgraded to latest cordova/phonegap versions (7.0.1/6.5.0) and it seems the viewport meta tag is ignored. Running old version I can see in the chrome devtools that html width is 1200px but with the newer version html width remains to 960px

Any idea about how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 6):

I finally could solve this issue by editing the MainActivity.java file in android platform folder.
This file declares a class that inherits from CordovaActivity and overrides the onCreate method. It seem that now is required to set a couple of settings in order the webview makes use of the "viewport" meta.

My onCreate method in MainActivity.java now looks like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // enable Cordova apps to be started in the background
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null && extras.getBoolean("cdvStartInBackground", false)) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml

    if(appView == null)
              init();

    WebView webView = (WebView)appView.getView();
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
   settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

   loadUrl(launchUrl);
}
```

The key is to call set "LoadWithOverviewMode" and "UseWideViewPort" to true.

Now app is working as expected

Comment: This plugin seems to apply the proposed fix automatically as part of a Cordova hook: https://github.com/cakuki/cordova-plugin-viewport

Comment: Finally solution that works. Thank you! Don't forget to import android.webkit.*;